# "orthogonal" and "parallel" morphisms?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Let $\mathbf C$ a category with an initial object named $0$.

Is there a name for the pair of arrows $f,g\colon A\to B$ such that the unique arrow $0\to A$ is their equalizer? And dually, is there a special name for $f,g\colon A\to B$ such that the coequalizer is $B\to 1$, when $1$ is the terminal object of $\mathbf C$? Finally, is it useful to name them? :)

I can figure out how it works in case $\mathbf C$ is concrete: I want to map the fact that a couple of arrows is "everywhere equal" (if "coker(f,g)=the whole") or "nowhere equal" (if "ker(f,g)=nothing unnecessary").

No ideas for general situation + I'm searching references (something make me think about Lawvere but I'm not able to recover anything).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The former might be called "having disjoint images", at least if C is extensive.  I think "everywhere equal" is the wrong intuition for the dual notion; for instance, $id_N\colon N\to N$ and $(+1)\colon N\to N$ have *both* properties.

Comment: I agree with Mike's comment about the intuition "everywhere equal", and that the former is something to do with disjointness. In fact Diers calls a pair with the latter property "codisjointed". 

Comment: For the first, surely "disjoint" (or even just "unequal" or "apart") would be enough: it's all about limits and no "image" need ever be formed. I wonder what happens under Stone duality if we apply this to parallel homomorphism that agree only on constants.

Comment: For the dual property, the situation in $\bf Set$ is a binary relation whose equivalence closure is the total relation, or "indiscriminate" as I called it in my book, so maybe we could
call this an indiscriminate pair. We could also think of the relation dynamically: it gets you from anywhere to anywhere else, which is called "transitive" in the theory of permutation groups.
However, some more examples in other categories would be useful before fixing a name.

Comment: Further to my objection to "disjoint <i>image</i>", consider the identity and swap maps $2\rightrightarrows 2$. These have the property of the question. However, their images are both $2\rightarrowtail 2$ and the intersection of these is again the whole of $2$, not $0$.

Comment: Good point Paul; "disjoint image" is misleading.  But I have no intuition for the meaning of "disjoint" except applied to subobjects, so my brain would tend to interpret plain "disjoint" as "having disjoint images," which as you point out is wrong.  So maybe "nowhere equal" is more appropriate.

Comment: When we say that "coproducts are disjoint" we mean that the pullback of the two inclusions is the initial object. Ah, that's not the same as the question.  Maybe Mike is right with "nowhere equal".  However, the dual question sounds more interesting.